# PHP preg_replace from @ to next space

Tags: php, function, preg-replace

im trying to create a function to replace from @ to next space but i cant seem to get it to work propely... i got the quote part to work but this is what i got so far:

```
function test($body) { 
    $find = array( 
        "/\[quote\](.+?)\[\/quote\]/is",
        "/@(.+?)/is" 
);
 $replace = array(
        "<div class=\"quote\">$1</div>",
        "<a href=\"user.php?profile=$1\">$1</a>"
    ); 
    $body = htmlspecialchars($body); 
    $body = preg_replace($find, $replace, $body); 
    return $body;
}
```

any help would be really appreciated.

example:

> [quote]
>
> @lalalala
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras viverra
>   ornare lectus sit amet dignissim. Vestibulum a mi leo. Nunc placerat
>   accumsan elit, nec luctus ante malesuada sed. Quisque at urna non erat
>   suscipit pharetra.
>
> [/quote]
>
> Morbi massa mauris, consequat vitae sem eu, maximus posuere ligula.
>   Fusce pretium ultricies lectus sit amet bibendum. Aliquam nec dolor
>   urna.

expected output:

```
<div class="quote"> 

<a href="user.php?profile=lalalala">lalalala</a>            

 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras viverra
 ornare lectus sit amet dignissim. Vestibulum a mi leo. Nunc placerat
 accumsan elit, nec luctus ante malesuada sed. Quisque at urna non erat
 suscipit pharetra. 

</div>

 Morbi massa mauris, consequat vitae sem eu, maximus posuere ligula.
 Fusce pretium ultricies lectus sit amet bibendum. Aliquam nec dolor
 urna.
```

Comment: Can you please give an example of `$body`

Comment: And please the expected output too.

Comment: @mega6382 there u go :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `\S` (not-space character): `/@(\S+)/is`

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace the regular expression `"/@(.+?)/is"` with `"/@\S+/"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following regex for the second one:

```
"/@(.+?)\s/is"
```

Here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/kj4LFF/1). This will select everything in the text until a space. OR better yet:

```
"/@(\w+)/is"
```

This will only select alphanumeric characters and underscore like `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kj4LFF/3)